# Image and range of linear transformation from subspace of $\mathrm{R^4}$ to $R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be subspace of $\mathrm{R^4}$ spanned by vectors $(1,0,1,2), (2,1,3,4)$ and $(3,1,4,6).$

$T : V \to \mathrm{R^2}$ is a linear transformation such that $T(x,y,z,t)= (x-y, z-t)$ for all $ (x,y,z,t)\in V.$ Find basis for range space and null space of $T.$

For null space; $x-y= 0, z-t= 0$ gives ker$\text(T)= \text{span} \{ (1,1,0,0), (0,0,1,1)\}$

Also, $T(1,0,1,2)= (1,-1)$, $T(2,1,3,4)= (1,-1)$ and $T(3,1,4,6)= (2,-2).$
So Image$\text(T)$= span $\{ (1,-1), (1,-1), (2,-2)\}=$ span $\{(1,-1)\}$

Is it correct or there come changes when standard basis is not given?

Comment: The image seems to be good, but the nullspace is not, because you did not check if they are in $V$ or not.

Comment: It'd also violate the rank-nullity theorem, because $\text{dim}V=2$ and $\text{nullity}V=1$ implies $\text{rank}V=1$.

Comment: @Botond thank you for the suggestion, I rechecked , ker$T= \text{span} \{(1,1,2,2)\}$

Comment: $T$ as you’ve defined it has a subset of $\mathbb R^4$ (namely $V$) for a domain, not $\mathbb R^2$. Don’t make the common mistake of calling a vector space that’s only isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ by that name.